# How to record console application process?

Tags: c#, console, record

I have a console application. I want to record all information displayed on the console window including the commands that I typed in and the information returned from that application. How to do? I am using C# language.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a list of strings and add each prompt and response to the list.  From there, you could write the recording to the console, write it to a file, or something else.

```
namespace RecordConsoleProgress
{
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using static System.Console;

    class Program
    {
        static List<string> recording = new List<string>();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string response = "";
            do
            {
                string prompt = "Please enter your input (Q <ENTER> to Quit): ";
                Write(prompt);
                recording.Add(prompt);
                response = ReadLine();
                recording.Add(response);
            } while (response != "Q");

            WriteLine("\nYour recording follows");
            foreach (string s in recording)
                WriteLine(s);

            ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```